# Java combining two strings

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a function that combines two strings using the rules below.

1. Symbols in string are taken by turns (first string first symbol, second string first symbol, first string second symbol and so on) : "jv" + "aa" = "java".
2. If shorter string reaches to the end, all symbols from another string are added to the end of the string that already ended :  "h" + "ello" = "hello".

this is what i have so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aa = "jv";
        String bb = "aa";
        System.out.println(combineStrings(aa, bb));


 }
   public static String combineStrings(String aa, String bb) {

     String newstring;
     if(aa.length() > bb.length()){

         for(int i = 0; i < aa.length(); i++){

             newstring  = aa.substring(i, 1) + bb.substring(i, 1);

         }

     } else {


     }


     return newstring;
 }
```

Comment: And what’s your question?

Comment: ... and the question?

Comment: what next you want to know ???

Comment: how do i do it? the code above gives me an error and i don't understand why

Comment: So what is the error? You should not expect everybody to compile and run your code.

Comment: Sorry for a bad post, but here is the error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The local variable newstring may not have been initialized

 at testjavafx2.testjavafx2.combineStrings(testjavafx2.java:125)
 at testjavafx2.testjavafx2.main(testjavafx2.java:97)

Comment: "The local variable newstring may not have been initialized"

Comment: Start with `String newstring = "";` and use `newstring += ...` instead of `newstring = ...`.

Comment: So `aa.length()` is <= `b.length()` and your code hits the empty else-block. This causes newstring to not be initalized so it cannot be returned.

Comment: That error message is pretty self-explanatory tbh. You've defined the vairable newString but potentially haven't assigned it to anything

Comment: Looks like an assignment to me

Comment: Yes it is an assignment, although it's an expired one. it's made for studying the exam.

Answer (score 3):

so initialize it

```
String newstring = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for this kind of `String` manipulation, using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is recommended:

```
public static String combineStrings(String aa, String bb) {
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(aa.length()+bb.length());
    int common=Math.min(aa.length(), bb.length());
    for(int ix=0; ix<common; ix++)
        sb.append(aa.charAt(ix)).append(bb.charAt(ix));
    String longer=aa.length()>bb.length()? aa: bb;
    sb.append(longer, common, longer.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: i tested it out, works perfectly. i'm trying to think this through now, this code is next level for me, i'm beginner.

Comment: Right, study the code and check out [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and you may learn something that help solving other related problems.

Comment: @sharonbn: that linked question does *not* involve loops nor adding only a part of another string like [`sb.append(longer, common, longer.length())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-int-int-) does. For code which can be expressed as `a + b`, there is indeed no need to use `StringBuilder`. But here, the code is not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to initialize your `newString` as an empty string first.

```
public class CombineStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aa = "aaaaa111";
        String bb = "bbbbb";
        System.out.println(combineStrings(aa, bb));
    }

    public static String combineStrings(String aa, String bb) {

        int shorterLength = (aa.length() >= bb.length()) ? 
                bb.length() : aa.length();

        // Initialize newString as empty string
        String newString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < shorterLength; i++) {
            newString += aa.charAt(i) + "" + bb.charAt(i);
        }

        newString += (aa.length() > bb.length()) ? 
                    aa.substring(shorterLength) :
                        bb.substring(shorterLength);

        return newString;
    }
}
```

A more optimized solution would be to make use of [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead!

Comment: Though your solution should work, you should use StringBuffer. String concatanation is slow.

Comment: @Aakash Yes, I totally agree that would be an even better solution! If you mean, StringBuilder.

Comment: Actually you should use StringBuilder, not StringBuffer.

Comment: Note that you can simplify your last statement to `newString += (aa.length()>bb.length()? aa: bb).substring(shorterLength);`

Comment: @Holger True! That would be better.

Answer (score 0):

`newstring` is not initialised on all control points. (The `else` block is blank).

Java doesn't allow this and is informing you of that.

One solution is to write `String newstring = null;` and deal with the `null` string possibility correctly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is probably not going to work. You could create a for-loop with an index counter starting at 0. In the loop get a character from both strings at the index position and add them to your result in the correct order. The result should not be a String but a StringBuilder to avoid interning all the intermediary String results. If either of the input Strings runs out then add the remainder of the other String and exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need function to join the strings as per your requirement.
Below should solve your problem

```
public static String combineStrings(String aa, String bb) {
     int lenA, lenB, min;
     lenA = aa.length();
     lenB = bb.length();
     min = Math.min(lenA, lenB);
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i = 0; i < min; i++){
         builder .append(aa.charAt(i));
         builder .append(bb.charAt(i));
     }
     if(min < lenA)
        builder .append(aa.substring(min));
     if(min < lenB)
        builder .append(bb.substring(min));

     return builder .toString();
 }
```

Comment: Unless you need Java 1.4 compatibility, using a `StringBuilder` rather than `StringBuffer` is the preferred choice. Besides that, you are appending a *number* rather than the remaining string at the end which suggests that you haven’t really tested your code…

Comment: absolutely correct. Thank you @Holger. Yes, I didn't had a chance to test my code cause I am having a new machine and still configuring that. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a recursive variation:

```
public static String combineStrings(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() > 0 && b.length() > 0) {
        return "" + a.charAt(0) + b.charAt(0)
                + combineStrings(a.substring(1), b.substring(1));
    } else {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

For performance you should go with Holger's solution (which I've already up-voted).